# TVS diode body touching

Tags: diodes, tvs

What is the electrical risk or impacts we could have if the [Semtech RClamp3331Z2C TVS diode](https://www.semtech.com/products/circuit-protection/low-capacitance/rclamp3331z2c) bodies in our PCB touch each other?

Comment: Welcome! Check the datasheets. Good ones will have a value for isolation voltage from the body to the circuit/chip inside. I doubt it would pose an issue. Do you have a datasheet link?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, the TVS diodes concerned are RClamp3331Z2C

Comment: Register to access datasheet? No thank you.

Comment: 01005 size smd?  How do the bodies touch without shorting the terminals?

Comment: The SMD 01005 TVS diode mounting diagram shows that the width of the stencil opening is about 0.298 mm and the TVS diode housing is 0.300 mm